# why the CSS transition doesn't work in the new dom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

When I use CSS transition like below.
https://jsfiddle.net/sunyuu/e58sfeva/17/

```js
var Main = {
    data () {
      return {
        isActive: false,
        childStyle: {}
      };
    },
    methods: {
      showMask() {
       this.isActive = true
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.childStyle = {
           transform: 'scale(2, 2)'
    }
        })
      },
      hideMask() {
       this.childStyle = {}
       this.isActive = false
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <button @click="showMask">click here</button>
    <div class="parent" v-if="isActive" @click="hideMask">
      <div v-bind:style="childStyle" class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

I expect the red cube would scale when the mask show.
But the transition doesn't work, I can't figure it out.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: it's working for me ... i see a transiton .. increase the vale of `0.3` and have a look

Comment: @TemaniAfif I chek again with chrome at both the win and Mac, it still not working.

Comment: am also on chrome ... try to replace 0.3 by 3 and see what is happening

Answer (score 2):

Transitions don't work when elements are added to the DOM. They are reacting to CSS properties changing.

Try using animation instead.

```css
@keyframes childScale {
  from {transform: scale(0, 0)}
  to {transform: scale(2, 2)}
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: childScale .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make CSS transition work, the dom must be available, without `display:none` set, and should have its initial pre-transition state value.